# A timeout (30000 milliseconds) was reached while waiting for a transaction response from the ReportServer service

Tags: reporting-services

I get the following error in EventViewer 
A timeout (30000 milliseconds) was reached while waiting for a transaction response from the ReportServer service.

Did someone else get this error? What produce it?

Answer (score 0):

We've had this from time to time. [The following link](http://geekswithblogs.net/ssrs/archive/2009/10/30/steps-to-resolve-ssrs-timeout-issues.aspx) has some great steps to help rectify this if it's a recurring issue for you.

In case this link is ever in-active in the future and somebody is looking for this content:

> **1) Set the HttpRuntime ExecutionTimeout value to a greater value** (ie 3
>   hours) on the Report Server
>
> How do you do this? Simple!
>
> a. Open the ReportServer’s Web.config file by going to Start ->
>   Administrative Tools -> Internet Information Services. 
>   b. From there, expand Web Sites -> Default Web Site, and click on
>   ReportServer. On the right-hand pane, right-click ‘Web.Config’ and
>   select ‘Open’. 
>   c. Locate the HttpRuntime parameter. If it doesn’t exist, you will have to create it within the 
>   section. 
>   d.      Set the executionTimeout value to ‘10800’ (3 hours)
>   as shown below:
>
> **2) Increase the script timeout on the report server**
>
> 1. Go onto your Reporting Server and open up Internet Information Services; right-click on the ReportServer and select Properties.
> 2. Go to the Options tab, and set the ASP Script timeout to 300 seconds as shown below.
>
> **3) Set the report to never time out on the server**
>
> 1. Open your web browser on the server and go to localhost/Reports
> 2. Navigate to the Report location and click on the problem report(s).
> 3. On the left-hand pane, click on Properties.
> 4. In the ‘Report Execution Timeout’ click the ‘Do not timeout report execution’.

Comment: Reporting Services is not using IIS since 2008.

Comment: @scar80 This question is four years old, a lot of people were still using 2008 back then!